# Knee Injury Recovery (possibly MCL)

Tags: knees, knee-pain, rehabilitation

I injured my knee during running (I'd say overuse). When resting, I can feel it only when extending the knee, maybe at 150°. It's inner knee pain, close to the kneecap but not under it. From googling, I think it is MCL. I can't see any swelling, so it must be very light if any. It's not painful nor limiting when walking but I can't run without pain longer than 15 minutes.

The only problem is that it happened again after a recovery. I believe I must have done something wrong during the recovery (2 weeks), not stretched enough before the run. After the first recovery (no pain or discomfort at all) I went for a light jog only but it started hurting again after those 15 minutes. I walked back with little discomfort, but no pain.

I've google all kinds of exercises for knee pain and strengthening, I have ibuprofen and ice packs. I need to know:

- How often should I do the exercises? I have a sedentary job.
- Is there any reason to ice the knee when there is no swelling?
- Is it better to keep the knee warm? (it's winter here now)
- Should I eat non-inflammatory pills if the pain is fine and again no visible swelling?

---

If I can't fully recover this time, I am going to see a doctor to rule out other problems.

Comment: You could probably save some time by seeing a sports physical therapist to find out what is going on with your knee.  They'll  evaluate your knee and give you specific exercises.

Comment: Just a note, recently I've had pain that felt like the joints and tendons in my legs had some problems from over training, but after I started using a roller mainly to massage a knot out of my calf all these pains went away. Nothing is guaranteed but I thought I'd let you know because its worth a try. Hope you get it under control.